# Copying C# BitArray to byte[] produces incorrect result

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, .net-core, bitarray

As mentioned in the title, when I copy a BitArray to a byte array, the resulting byte array contains the correct values but in the wrong order.

So here is a small snippet of code I created that demonstrates the issue:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(new bool[] {   false,false,true,false,false,true,false,false,
                                                    true,false,false,true,false,false,true,false,
                                                    false,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,
                                                    false,true,true,false,true,true,false,true,
                                                    true,false,true,true,false,true,true,false,
                                                    true,true,false,true,true,false,true,true,
                                                    false,false,true,false,false,true,false,false,
                                                    true,false,false,true,false,false,true,false,
                                                    false,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,});

byte[] bytes = new byte[bits.Length / 8];
bits.CopyTo(bytes, 0);

foreach ( byte b in bytes )
    Console.WriteLine(b);
```

From my understanding, printing these byte values should give the results written below. Based on the fact that each byte is a value derived from the corresponding 8 bits in the BitArray.

1. 00100100 = 36
2. 10010010 = 146
3. 01001001 = 73
4. 01101101 = 109
5. 10110110 = 182
6. 11011011 = 219
7. 00100100 = 36
8. 10010010 = 146
9. 01001001 = 73

However, these results are not the ones output in my code. Instead, I get the same byte values but in a different, seemingly arbitrary order:

[image: output]

Does anyone know why this is the case or alternatively another efficient way to convert a BitArray object to an array of bytes?

Comment: Reverse the order of the input (bool) array, then reverse the order of the output (byte) array, and you'll get the output you expect.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Really dumb that it doesn't copy it in the correct order.

Comment: It is copying in little-endian order, but you are interpreting it in big-endian.